# How to set default value to <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to set default value to h:selectOneMenu. But, It is not working.

This is my code

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
        <h:form id="test">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectMenuBean.selectedItem}"
                         title="select version"
                         onchange="submit()"
                         disabled="false" id="combo">

            <f:selectItems value="#{selectMenuBean.selectItems}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

**BackingBean**

```
private String selectedItem;
private List selectItems;
private int version=3;

public List getSelectItems() {

    List<Version> selectedItems = ExportDao.getVersionsList();
    System.out.println("List size: "+selectedItems.size());
    selectItems = new ArrayList();

    for (Version v1 : selectedItems) {
        String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
        //Create object of SimpleDateFormat and pass the desired date format.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(v1.getVersion(), "V" + v1.getVersion() + "/" + sdf.format(v1.getDate())));
        if(version = v1.getVersion()) // I have to check the version and set the matching version as selected.
        selectedItem = "V" + v1.getVersion() + "/" + sdf.format(v1.getDate());

    }
    return selectItems;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few possible solutions:

1) Set the type of selectItems to `SelectItem[]` instead of and untyped `List`.

or 2) Try setting the var, itemValue and itemLabel attributes of the selectItems like below, and put actual Version objects in your list.

or my favorite, 3) Make a VersionConverter that knows how to convert a Version object from and to a String. Example below if your Version object is persisted in a database and has an Id. After this is constructed, your selectedItem and List selectItems should have the typ Version (and List), not String. JSF will handle the conversion by itself.

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Version.class)
public class VersionConverter implements Converter{

    public VersionConverter() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            // Get an EJB that can fetch the Version from a DB. Alternativly, do whatever you need to get your object from a string.
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

            MyDao myDao = (MyDao)ic.lookup(String.format("java:global/%s/MyBean", (String)ic.lookup("java:module/ModuleName")));
            return myDao.findEntity(Version.class, getKey(value));
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    Long getKey(String value) {
        Long key;
        key = Long.valueOf(value);
        return key;
    }

    String getStringKey(Long value) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(value);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (object instanceof Version) {
            Version e = (Version) object;
            return getStringKey(e.getId());
        }
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("object " + object + " is of type " + object.getClass().getName() + "; expected type: " + Version.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Franke, Thank you for the reply. I will try this solution.

Answer (score 4):

You're setting the `selectedItem` with the item label instead of the item value.

Replace

```
selectedItem = "V" + v1.getVersion() + "/" + sdf.format(v1.getDate());
```

by

```
selectedItem = v1.getVersion();
```

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have changed it like as you said. Still, no luck. I am printing the selectedItem. It is printing the selected one but, It is not setting the value.